# Upload tracked files in github

Tags: git, github

I cannot Upload my laravel project into GitHub. Because here display some error this error is cannot upload an untracked file.

Comment: Can you please explain how you upload that files?

Comment: Please explain how you upload the files and what kind of error you produce.

Comment: Git error: src refspec master does not match any

Comment: Please post the actual commands you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload individual files which, I assume, is what you're trying to do because of that error message you commented (`Git error: src refspec master does not match any`).

Try running the following:

`git add path_to_your_file`

`git commit -m "message explaining what that file is or why it was added"`

`git push origin master`

That will add your file to a blob and create a commit that references that blob. Then that `git push` will upload the commit object to Github.